# Google custom search API HTTPError

Tags: python, web-crawler, google-custom-search

I follow the tutor in google customer search API

At first everything works, but after try for a while, i get error like this and ask me to pay billing :

HttpError: https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=AIzaSyD0R6X3ttYNUruF47s8oXT9pq1inzKi6cc&q=lectures&cx=006243837828428819664%3Aiikcd-xm0hu&alt=json returned "Access Not Configured. CustomSearch API has not been used in project 1042260221982 before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/customsearch/overview?project=1042260221982 then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.">

My code is this(from github):
    from googleapiclient.discovery import build

```
def main():
    service = build("customsearch", "v1",
        developerKey="AIzaSyD0R6X3ttYNUruF47s8oXT9pq1inzKi6cc")

    res = service.cse().list(
      q='lectures',
      cx='006243837828428819664:iikcd-xm0hu',
    ).execute()
    for item in res['items']:
        print(item)

main()
```

does this mean I use this API too much ?
I try to use another google account to get another IAP and search engine id, still didn't work.